# How make attribute of model only for user.is_staff?

Tags: python, django

Model `Post` has the boolean field `moderation`, which is intended for publishing after approval by admin users (which have `user.is_staff` as `True`.

There is a page "Post update", where an user (the author of the post) and admin users can updated the post info.
I want that the field `moderation` (which is a checkbox) is shown only if the user is an admin (`user.is_staff == True`).

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    moderation = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    ...
```

**forms.py**

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'body', 'logo']
```

**views.py**

```
class PostUpdateView(PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'body', 'logo']
    permission_required = 'post.can_mark_returned'
```

**post_form.html**

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to reformulate "I need the this attribut was only in user.is_staff on the page "Post update" "? It is currently difficult to understand what you need exactly

Comment: Do you mean to say that you only want the checkbox "moderation" visible in the form when the logged in user is staff?

Comment: @9769953 yeah))

Comment: Note: your class `PostForm` is never used, as the view `PostUpdateView` creates its own form class based on the specified fields.

Comment: @Ralf Even in the case of creating a new record?

Comment: If you use `CreateView`, then that too builds its own form class if you specified the `fields` on that view. However, if you want to use your own form, you can specify it using the attribute `form_class`, just like [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#basic-forms) in the docs shows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6717249/9225671) has some ideas for you.

---

I can also suggest overriding [`FormMixin.get_form_class()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_class) and using [`modelform_factory()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/models/#modelform-factory):

```
from django.forms import modelform_factory

class PostUpdateView(PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    permission_required = 'post.can_mark_returned'

    def get_form_class(self)
        fields = ['title', 'body', 'logo']
        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            fields.append('moderation')

        return modelform_factory(
            self.model,
            fields=fields)
```